# fscanf reads one line out of 7 wrong

Tags: c, scanf, jpeg

I have a zipped text file with 7 very long lines of text containing information for the decoding of a JPEG encoded file.

When I try to read the unzipped File with my C program, line by line with `fscanf`, I get the first 3 and the last 3 lines correctly, just the 4th line isn't read as a string as expected.

The output of the 4th line is a very long string filled with `1` and `0`.

If I look at the input file with Notepad or a hex editor everything looks fine as it should.
If I manually create a text file with the same structure (but with shorter lines) `fscanf` works fine.
There is no difference if I unzip the File with my program or do it manually.

```
FILE *tmpdata;
char enc_path[256];
int arrsize;
// Building the absolute Path
sprintf(enc_path, "%s%stmp.txt", dest, src_name);

arrsize = unzip(); // gives back size of the file

// not the best way to create the output strings, 
// but I don't know the size of the lines.

char masse[10];
char ytabelle[arrsize / 3];
char cbtabelle[arrsize / 3];
char crtabelle[arrsize / 2];
char ywerte[arrsize  /3];
char cbwerte[arrsize / 3];
char crwerte[arrsize / 3];

if ((tmpdata = fopen(enc_path, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error: can´t read input file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

fscanf(tmpdata, "%s %s %s  %s %s %s %s", masse, ytabelle, cbtabelle, crtabelle, ywerte, cbwerte, crwerte);
```

The input file looks like:

```
512x512
Y{42:110000;13:111000;...;0:0;}
CB{42:110000;13:111000;...;0:0;}
CR{42:110000;13:111000;...;0:0;}
000111010010111001110000111100011...
100011011101110001101000011100110...
100011101110110111011001100111011...
```

if I print the separate strings:

```
512x512
Y{42:110000;13:111000;...;0:0;}
CB{42:110000;13:111000;...;0:0;}
111001111111111000110000111111000...
000111010010111001110000111100011...
100011011101110001101000011100110...
100011101110110111011001100111011...
```

Comment: The `arraysize/2` for just one of the arrays is a copy/paste error?

Comment: The size 'char crtabelle[arrsize/2]' does not look like adequate. Maybe this assumption is true. Increase the size or follow a different approach.

Comment: Do you know that `fscanf` returns a value an %s reads a long string

Comment: arraysize/2 was just a experiment to increase the size, but didn´t changed the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiples reasons for your program to not behave properly:

- you may allocate too much data with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*), causing erratic behavior.
- the strings int the file might contain embedded spaces, causing `fscanf()` to read words instead of lines.
- you do not tell `fscanf()` the size of the destination arrays. `fscanf()` may store data beyond the end of the destination arrays, overflowing into the next array (which would explain the observed behavior) or causing some other undefined behavior.

It is very cumbersome to pass the size of the destination arrays when they are not simple constants. I suggest you use `fgets()` instead of `fscanf()` to read the file contents and allocate the arrays with `malloc()` to a larger size to avoid problems:

```c
    FILE *tmpdata;
    char enc_path[256];
    size_t arrsize;

    // Building the absolute path
    snprintf(enc_path, sizeof enc_path, "%s%stmp.txt", dest, src_name);

    arrsize = unzip(); // gives back size of the file

    // not the best way to create the output strings, 
    // but I don't know the size of the lines.

    char masse[16];
    size_t ytabelle_size = arrsize + 2;
    size_t cbtabelle_size = arrsize + 2;
    size_t crtabelle_size = arrsize + 2;
    char *ytabelle = malloc(ytabelle_size);
    char *cbtabelle = malloc(cbtabelle_size);
    char *crtabelle = malloc(crtabelle_size);
    size_t ywerte_size = arrsize + 2;
    size_t cbwerte_size = arrsize + 2;
    size_t crwerte_size = arrsize + 2;
    char *ywerte = malloc(ywerte_size);
    char *cbwerte = malloc(cbwerte_size);
    char *crwerte = malloc(crwerte_size);

    if (!ytabelle ||!cbtabelle ||!crtabelle ||!ywerte ||!cbwerte ||!crwerte) {
        printf("Error: cannot allocate memory\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ((tmpdata = fopen(enc_path, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: cannot open input file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (!fgets(masse, sizeof masse, tmpdata)
    ||  !fgets(ytabelle, ytabelle_size, tmpdata)
    ||  !fgets(cbtabelle, cbtabelle_size, tmpdata)
    ||  !fgets(crtabelle, crtabelle_size, tmpdata)
    ||  !fgets(ywerte, ywerte_size, tmpdata)
    ||  !fgets(cbwerte, cbwerte_size, tmpdata)
    ||  !fgets(crwerte, crwerte_size, tmpdata)) {
        printf("Error: cannot read input file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // file contents were read, arrays should have a trailing newline, which
    // you should strip or handle in the decoding phase.
    ...
```

If you are using the GNUlibc or some modern Posix systems, you could use the `m` prefix in `fscanf()` to allocate the space for the words read from the file. Using this allows for a simpler but non portable solution:

```c
    FILE *tmpdata;
    char enc_path[256];
    size_t arrsize;

    // Building the absolute path
    snprintf(enc_path, sizeof enc_path, "%s%stmp.txt", dest, src_name);

    arrsize = unzip(); // gives back size of the file

    // not the best way to create the output strings, 
    // but I don't know the size of the lines.

    char masse[16];
    char *ytabelle = NULL;
    char *cbtabelle = NULL;
    char *crtabelle = NULL;
    char *ywerte = NULL;
    char *cbwerte = NULL;
    char *crwerte = NULL;

    if ((tmpdata = fopen(enc_path, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: cannot open input file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fscanf(tmpdata, "%ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms %ms", &masse,
               &ytabelle, &cbtabelle, &crtabelle,
               &ywerte, &cbwerte, &crwerte) != 7) {
        printf("Error: cannot read input file\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ...
```

---

PS: Unlike German, the initial letters of nouns are not capitalized in English, except for some exceptions such as language, people and place names.

Comment: Thank you very much.
fgets works fine and gives me the right string.

PS: Sorry for the bad writing, it´s a bit hard for me to switch between English and German writing after 8 hours of work and 40° Celsius outside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe avoid stack allocation??

```
char masse[10];
char *ytabelle  = malloc(arrsize/3); if (!ytabelle)  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char *cbtabelle = malloc(arrsize/3); if (!cbtabelle) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char *crtabelle = malloc(arrsize/2); if (!crtabelle) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char *ywerte    = malloc(arrsize/3); if (!ywerte)    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char *cbwerte   = malloc(arrsize/3); if (!cbwerte)   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
char *crwerte   = malloc(arrsize/3); if (!crwerte)   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

/* use as before */

free(ytabelle);
free(cbtabelle);
free(crtabelle);
free(ywerte);
free(cbwerte);
free(crwerte);
```